# How can I increase the width of a panel using jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

```
<div><a href="#overlayPanel">
    search</a>
</div>

<div data-role="panel"
     id="overlayPanel" 
     data-theme="a"  
     data-display="overlay"                                                 
     data-position="right" style="width:100%">
         <h2>Overlay Panel</h2> 
         <a href="#pageone" data-rel="close">
             Close panel
         </a>
</div>
```

I tried above code using jquery mobiles, its increasing the size but its closing automatically when we click any where in the panel

Answer (score 2):

Set `data-dismissible` property to `false` in your panel.
Like this

```
<div data-role="panel" id="myPanel" data-dismissible="false" style="width:100%">
```

Refer this **<kbd>[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hRXns/1/)</kbd>**

Comment: When i use style="width:100%" its adding extra space at right side,Its showing extra space when we open it on mobile phone only in firefox browser.How i have to remove this extra space please help me.

Comment: @user3350169 remove style width and try.

Comment: But i want panel to take whole page,how can i make it to take whole page